# Implementing MongoDB search engine API in Flask

Tags: python, json, mongodb, full-text-search, flask-restful

I am new to MongoDB and I am trying to build a simple search page using MongoDB in Flask.

I have a **restaurants.json** ingested into MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57506d62f57802807471dd42"), "name" : "456 Cookies Shop", "contact" : { "phone" : "604-555-0149", "email" : "456CookiesShop@example.org", "location" : [ -73.8850023, 40.7494272 ] }, "stars" : 4, "categories" : [ "Bakery", "Cookies", "Cake", "Coffee" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57506d62f57802807471dd28"), "name" : "XYZ Bagels Restaurant", "contact" : { "phone" : "435-555-0190", "email" : "XYZBagelsRestaurant@example.net", "location" : [ -74.0707363, 40.59321569999999 ] }, "stars" : 4, "categories" : [ "Bagels", "Sandwiches", "Coffee" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57506d62f57802807471dd44"), "name" : "XYZ Steak Buffet", "contact" : { "phone" : "229-555-0197", "email" : "XYZSteakBuffet@example.org", "location" : [ -73.9799932, 40.7660886 ] }, "stars" : 3, "categories" : [ "Steak", "Salad", "Chinese" ] }
```

**search.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, session, redirect, jsonify
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
mongo = PyMongo(app)
db = client.dummy
collection = db.restaurants

@app.route('/search', methods = ['GET'])
def search():
    search = mongo.db.collection
    output = []
    for q in search.find():
        output.append({'name' : q['name'], 'categories' : q['categories']})
    return jsonify({'result' : output})

@app.route('/search/<name>', methods = ['GET'])
def search_by_keyword(name):
    search_by_keyword = mongo.db.collection
    q = search_by_keyword.find_one({'name' : name})
    output = {'name' : q['name']}

    return jsonify({'results' : output})

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

**search.html**:

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=post>
  <dl>
    {{ render_field(form.select) }}
    <p>
    {{ render_field(form.search) }}
  </dl>
  <p><input type=submit value=Search>
</form>
```

**forms.py**:

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, SelectField

class SearchForm(Form):
    choices = [('name', 'name'),
           ('categories', 'categories')]
    select = SelectField('Search:', choices = choices)
    search = StringField('')
```

- How do I make a keyword search to search on all Mongo fields, not just the one I specified (name)?
- How do I make json output file to be posted as a search result in html?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `text` index on the field you are interested or on all fields using wildcard `*`

To create index on `name` and `categories`

```
db.restaurants.ensureIndex({"name" : "text", "categories" : "text"})
```

To create index on all fields `*`

```
db.restaurants.ensureIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

search for a string

```
> db.restaurants.find({$text : {$search : "XYZ", $caseSensitive : false}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57506d62f57802807471dd44"), "name" : "XYZ Steak Buffet", "contact" : { "phone" : "229-555-0197", "email" : "XYZSteakBuffet@example.org", "location" : [ -73.9799932, 40.7660886 ] }, "stars" : 3, "categories" : [ "Steak", "Salad", "Chinese" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57506d62f57802807471dd28"), "name" : "XYZ Bagels Restaurant", "contact" : { "phone" : "435-555-0190", "email" : "XYZBagelsRestaurant@example.net", "location" : [ -74.0707363, 40.59321569999999 ] }, "stars" : 4, "categories" : [ "Bagels", "Sandwiches", "Coffee" ] }
```

search for a string which is in `categories` array

```
> db.restaurants.find({$text : {$search : "Chinese", $caseSensitive : false}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57506d62f57802807471dd44"), "name" : "XYZ Steak Buffet", "contact" : { "phone" : "229-555-0197", "email" : "XYZSteakBuffet@example.org", "location" : [ -73.9799932, 40.7660886 ] }, "stars" : 3, "categories" : [ "Steak", "Salad", "Chinese" ] }
>
```

you can use the return json to render in page

[Mongo Text Index Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)

[Text search usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html)

show indices

```
> db.restaurants.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "bitcoin.restaurants"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "name_text_categories_text",
        "ns" : "bitcoin.restaurants",
        "weights" : {
            "categories" : 1,
            "name" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
```